# Rails 3.2 and simple_datatables - Why isn't my table loading?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm trying to use the simple_datatables gem, but [the docs](https://github.com/gryphon/simple_datatables) aren't so clear.

When I load up search.datatables and search.html in my browser, I get JSON content, but when I use my index view, my table is not getting populated.

I've created app/views/trades/search.jsonify with this content:

```
@trades.each do |t|
  json << [
    t.tddt,
    ... # omitted for brevity
    t.sdbk,
  ]
end
```

And I've added the "search" controller action to my TradesController:

```
respond_to :html, :datatables

def search
  @trades = Trade.search(params[:search])
  respond_with @trades
end

def index
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # index.html.erb
  end
end
```

And similarly, as indicated by the docs, I've added this javascript to my app/views/index.html.erb:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$("#trades_tbl").dataTable({
    "sAjaxSource" : "/trades/search.datatables",
    "aaSorting" : [[0,'asc']],
    "aoColumns" : [
      {"sName":"tddt"},
      ... // again omitted for brevity
      {"sName":"sdbk"},
    ],
    "bServerSide"  : true,
    "fnServerData" : simpleDatatables
  });

</script>
```

And here is the table in that same file:

```
<table id="trades_tbl">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Tddt</th>
      <!-- more columns omitted for brevity -->
      <th>Sdbk</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody/>
</table>
```

So what am I missing?  Why isn't the javascript loading my table?

Thanks.

**NOTE:** If someone with 1500+ reputation would be so kind as to create a simple_datatables tag, I think that would be a good thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few ideas I have:

To confirm, you added the following to your application.js asset pipeline manifest file:

```
//= require simple_datatables
```

and restarted the web server?

Another possible snag is the javascript inside index.html executing prior to the document being done loading, you may want to wrap the javascript inside the index.html inside a $(document).ready callback, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#trades_tbl").dataTable({
    ....
  });
});
```

Final idea: does the web browser development console indicate there are any javascript errors occurring? If so, you may want to resolve those.

Comment: I can't believe I forgot to wrap the Javascript with the $(document).ready callback.  Thanks a lot.